Can't build/deploy to github pages my NextJS app after implementing next-intl
So i've added the generateStaticParams to my app/[locale]/layout.tsx file and unstable_setRequestLocale to all the layout and page files refering to the next-intl docs
and i get the following error while github tries to build it.
Injecting property=output and value=export in:
import createNextIntlPlugin from 'next-intl/plugin';
 
const withNextIntl = createNextIntlPlugin();
 
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};
 
export default withNextIntl(nextConfig);
Error: TypeError: error must be an instance of Error



my app/[locale]/layout.tsx looks like this:
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import {NextIntlClientProvider} from 'next-intl';
import {getMessages} from 'next-intl/server';
import {unstable_setRequestLocale} from 'next-intl/server';

const locales = ['en', 'pt'];

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return locales.map((locale) => ({locale}));
}



const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });


export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: {locale},
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params:{
    locale: string;
  }
  

  
}>) 



{
  unstable_setRequestLocale(locale);


  const messages = await getMessages();
 

  return (
    <html lang={locale}>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
        {children}
        </NextIntlClientProvider>
        </body>
    </html>
  );
}


it says i need to call this function in every layout and page files, but in my main (/app/[locale]/page.tsx) file, i can't call it since i'm using "use client".
so in dev build it works fine, but once i try to push it to github it throws me that error.
i'm sorry if this is not enough information, i'm new to nextjs.

Keep [locale]/page.tsx Server Component and move all interactivity to a nested client component

if you are using the standard NextJS workflow by Github Action (https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/nextjs.yml) I solved the issue removing the option:
with:
  static_site_generator: next

I found the solution on this github issue: https://github.com/actions/configure-pages/issues/107.
